# In Unreal, what are the differences between C++'s float and FFloat32?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, floating-point

I have been trying to learn some deeper aspects of UE4 and while reading many examples codes and also the source base of the engine, I noticed that sometimes people (and the very source code) use the standard C++ `float` primitive, but sometimes use UE4's custom implementation `FFloat32`.

Then I got curious: when programming a game with Unreal, what are the differences between using those 2 options and possibly what are the main cases when one should drop the standard C++ primitive in favor of the engine's implementation?

Comment: I'd be interested in reading the examples you've found that actually use `FFloat32`.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Some of them were off-line, a couple were online. As soon as I have time at home, I will search for them to share

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`float`, is well, a C++ floating point. `FFloat32` is a structure that represents a float as well as (via a union) the decomposed bitfields for that float's sign, mantissa and exponent parts.

You should generally *never* use `FFloat32` except when:

- you're using some API that expects a `FFloat32` (these are very rare) or
- you need to do some kind of low-level bit hackery with a floating point value (also fairly rare these days)

It's not that `FFloat32` is *bad*, per se, it's just that it doesn't really offer you anything you'd need for general-purpose floating point usage.

It is less common than a plain old `float`, which has some minor readability impact (others may not know immediately what it is for at a glance). It also doesn't implicitly convert to `float` so you'll be typing `something.FloatValue` a lot, which is also not a big deal, but could get tedious.

Finally, its use of unions and bitfields is non-portable, and implementation-defined (see below). This is not *your* problem, it is Epic's job to make sure the type is structured so that it's usable for all supported implementations, but it's a potential source of bugs if they fail to catch an issue with the implementation of the type when a new compiler version is released or added to the list of supported compilers.

So unless you have a need to play with the individual bits in the floating point representation, you should probably just avoid `FFloat32` (its cousin, `FFloat16`, may have slightly more utility as there is no standard 16-bit C++ floating point type).

It used to be common to manipulate floats via integer representations of their components for "[speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#History_and_investigation)." Modern computers obviate much of that need for many platforms, and the various [type-punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) techniques that could be used to do this sort of thing can actually be detrimental to performance or correctness in any event.

It should be telling that a search of Unreal's GitHub repository reveals very few uses of the `FFloat32` type. All of them are in the the definition of  `FFloat32` itself or in the definition of `FFloat16`.

---

Specifically, `FFloat32` does two things which the C++ standard calls out. It:

- allows you to act as if more than one member of the union is active at one time; you are expected to write to the floating point members and read from one of the integer members (9.5.1, [class.union])
- expects the bitfield allocation within the union to match that of the bit allocation of an IEEE floating point value; however, allocation and alignment of bitfield members within a class type is implementation defined (9.6.1, [class.bit])

Comment: Unreal is not written in standard C++, it's written for the particular compilers it's written for, so as long as they do the expected thing the standard is irrelevant.

Comment: I would expect those bitfields to be quite portable even in standard C/C++, since they are defined by an IEEE standard, and any compiler using a different layout for `float` would get *not IEEE 754 compliant* red mark (and compatibility troubles with lots of existing software).

Comment: The (pedantic) issue is that the written order of those bit fields may match the IEEE standard, but the C++ compiler may reorder or re-align them. This is only a minor footnote though since dealing with that is Epic's job; they should monitor each new compiler version to verify the type works correctly.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Point taken, thanks for clarification.

Comment: @JoshPetrie The C++ standard only specifies minimum sizes for primitives like float. While float must be _at least_ 4 bytes, it's possible it could be bigger. So perhaps add in the answer that FFloat32 is guaranteed to be 32 bits/4 bytes?

Comment: @JustinLardinois But FFloat32 contains a `float` member in the union, so if `float` is actually larger than 32 bits the overall `FFloat32` will be as well since the union must be large enough to hold the biggest member. In cases where floats are bigger than four bytes Epic will have had to modify the bitfield parts of the union as well to address that, otherwise they won't map the complete float.

Comment: Thanks for such a complete and detailed answer. Great one!